# What is particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my book,

$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=r(x) \tag{1}$$
$$ y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 \tag{2} $$

Here $(1)$ is full equation but $(2)$ is reduced equation. Suppose that in some way we know that $y(x,c_1 ,c_ 2 )$ is the general
solution of $(2)$-we expect it to contain two arbitrary constants since the
equation is of the second order-and that $y_p (x)$ is a fixed particular
solution of $(1)$. If $y(x)$ is any solution whatever of $(1)$, then an easy
calculation shows that $y(x) - y_p(x)$ is a solution of $(2)$ :
$$(y - y_p )'' + P(x)(y - y_p ) ' + Q(x)(y - y_p )= r(x)-r(x)=0$$

So $y(x)=y(x,c_1,c_2)+y_p$

Here I do not understand what it is meant by $y(x,c_1,c_2)$ and $y_p$,because I don't know what a particular solution means. Can you help me to understand?

Answer (score 1):

The notation $y(x, c_1, c_2)$ is just function notation. It says that $y$ depends on $x, c_1,$ and $c_2$. Without ICs we can't determine the constants.

Now, $y_p$ is called the *particular solution.* This is used to generate whatever the forcing function on the right side is. This is obtained by variation of parameters, undetermined coefficients, and the like. We obtain $y_p$ in whole by taking $c_1, c_2 = 0$ once we have found our full solution $y = y_c + y_p$, where $y_c$ satisfies $y'' +Py'+Qy = 0$.